# How do I get google maps to show the information bubble with the delegate?

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios8, xcode6

I've got a map which shows multiple pins, it also has information attached to them when I click on the pins. However, when I add the protocol GMSMapViewDelegate and do

```
mapView_.delegate = self;
```

The pins stop reacting to touch events (as in the information bubbles stop coming up), but the delegate methods below begin working as expected:

```
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
NSLog(@"tapped marker");
return YES;
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker 
{
NSLog(@"tapped info");
}
```

My question is do I have to show the info programatically from the didTapMarker method as soon as I set the delegate? I can't find anyone online having the same problem! To me logic would indicate they should still work, but obviously not..

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

edit: oh by the way, I obviously can't get to the second method as there is no information bubble being shown. just the first one works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, all I had to do was:

```
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
[mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.